# Add support for iPhone 4s and above on app store

Tags: ios, app-store, testflight

I uploaded application to testflight and it available for iphone 5s and above. I changed Valid Architectures from arm64 to arm64 armv7 armv7s. But nothing changed.[image: My architectures settings]

Maybe someone know how to fix it? If you need some additional information - just ask me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to support iPhone 4s screen size.

Read it. For Screen sizes
http://www.idev101.com/code/User_Interface/sizes.html

Read it

https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#functionality
POINT : 2.10

> iPhone Apps must also run on iPad without modification, at iPhone
>   resolution, and at 2X iPhone 3GS resolution

Thanks

Comment: Thank for your reply. I used assets with launch image. There are all images. I think the reason isn't in launch images.